# Usernames may not be synced on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, display-names

I use the name "Popular Demand" here on Meta, but everywhere else I'm "Lord Torgamus." (Fun fact: neither one of these is the name on my birth certificate!) I just visited stackexchange.com and was surprised to see both names there, in different places. I'm not sure that this is a bug, or how it could really affect anything, but it seemed weird enough that I figured it was worth reporting. Screenshot:

[image: main profile name does not match name in network header bar]

Comment: Only first time when you visit there? or always like that?

Comment: I don't think the age is right, nor the website...

Comment: @YOU, I almost never visit that page, but `Ctrl`+`F5` isn't changing it now.

Comment: @studiohack, because he set it like that on Stack Overflow, data got synced automatically (I think) but his top menu is still Popular Demand.

Comment: @studiohack, you're right, but those errors are by design.

Comment: @Popular, It would be funny if username on the top bar based on your meta profile, because you have most reputation here?

Comment: @YOU, I had the same thought, but haven't the slightest clue as to whether or not it's true.

Comment: I know some things use your oldest account, and some use the one with the most rep, but I have no idea how this particular page works

Comment: Hah! For once, something that affects you but not me when it comes to cross-site tomfoolery! ♪

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display name that appears in your network profile page is always approximately up-to-date (max 24 hours old). The display name in the top nav is only visible to you, but can be different and apparently out-of-sync.

We've added a nightly task to keep SE.com display names in sync. I just ran it once, and 3177 display names (including yours) were fixed up.

Comment: Ah, you even picked the right one. Grazie!

Comment: @Emmett Could you run the task again, please? My username on that screen has been out of sync for several months now. TIA!

Comment: @MrLister Looks like your stackexchange.com displaynaem is also Mr Lister? Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Oh... I did have 2 different names on that page, just like in the screenshot above, but I noticed it had changed shortly after I posted this comment, and I assumed you had taken care of it. Apparently someone else did; all is OK now. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Glad to hear it mysteriously fixed itself! :)

Comment: and... [it's back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160397/names-do-not-match-on-the-stack-exchange-site-header).