# Email and Username inconsistencies on StackExchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, display-names, stackexchange.com

> **EDIT:** Looks like the miraculous return of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90155/usernames-may-not-be-synced-on-stackexchange-com) bug, which was apparently fixed over a year ago.

([Reported partially before, but mistakenly marked status-bydesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121977/166307))

I recently changed my username to Arbiter on an SE sites and noticed it had changed from Purmou to Arbiter on StackExchange.com.

I then clicked on my username to find that my profile was still displaying the old one. (This is far too serious for freehand circles, so I went with **freehand emphasis bubbles** and **blocky question marks**!)

[image]

It turns out that [the header is only different when you also change the email on that account](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1081889#1081889). I can't actually test this since I can't reset my username for another 5 days.

Which leads into the other problem (and suggests that it might stem from the same root issue): after changing my email on the same site, I now receive tag subscription emails in the inbox of that email, and not the one I have set on the site where the subscribed tag lives.

In other words, Stack Overflow tag subscription emails are being sent to the email address on my newly changed account. That is the only account I use that email address on.

I have already tried syncing with my oldest account to no avail.

So, what could possibly be causing these inconsistencies?

Comment: I changed my username and e-mail on diy and now see the same bug.

Comment: I see "The Element of Magic" in my Stack Exchange header these days. That was only my name on MSO, and (as you can see) I changed it several weeks ago but it hasn't updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We now trigger a display name fix-up whenever you (a) log in or (b) view your *own* network profile.

Comment: Regarding the other problem you mentioned: tag subscription/filter emails always go to the email associated with your oldest account in the network. We'll consider respecting the emails associated with individual accounts, but it's complicated by the fact that filters can include tags from multiple sites.