# Changing my username on stackexchange.com in the main profile on stackexchange.com

Tags: support, display-names

How do I change my username on http://stackexchange.com, as in the main profile, not an individual site profile?

Edit: this question was closed as a duplicate, but it isn't really.
However, I did find [Email and Username inconsistencies on StackExchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145626/email-and-username-inconsistencies-on-stackexchange-com?lq=1) later, which it really is a duplicate of. So no real harm done.

PS I'm not sure if it's good practice to change the automatically inserted link to the correct one.

Comment: Go to your profile on any of the sites, click on edit and change your display name.

Comment: @Bart No, I don't want to change the "Mr Lister" on, I want to change the "Discount Gucci Unicorns" one, that only appears on http://stackexchange.com and where I don't have an "edit" link.

Comment: @JoshMein Not a duplicate. The answer on that one shows an "edit" link. The page I'm asking about doesn't have that link!

Comment: @MrLister Hmm, and "save and copy to all stack exchange accounts" does not replace that? If not, then I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: @Bart "Save and copy to all SE accounts" also overwrites all "About me" info boxes with the same information; I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: You don't really have a username on StackExchange.com, because you don't really have a Stack Exchange profile. It just pulls in data from your other profiles [in an inconsistent way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145626/email-and-username-inconsistencies-on-stackexchange-com).

Answer (score 4):

If I look at [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/79630/kiamlaluno), I see the following phrase written under the "About Me" box:

> Sync with oldest profile (Stack Overflow). Last sync 0s ago.

The "Sync with oldest profile (Stack Overflow)" is a link that forces synchronizing the network account with the oldest account you are using.

It means you can change the name that appears in your network profile by changing it in your oldest profile and clicking on the **Sync with oldest profile** link.

[image: screenshot]

#### Update

It seems your username has been correctly updated.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: But this is my oldest profile! The other name belongs to another account that has long been deleted.

Comment: I am sorry if there are hand-written circles: It seems I lost that feature with the last update of the tool I am using for taking screenshots.

Comment: Oh... interesting. I'm not sure if that was anything I did, or if someone manually refreshed it after seeing my post.

Comment: @MrLister The instructions given in this answer worked for you, just like they did for me.