# Names do not match on the Stack Exchange site header

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Email and Username inconsistencies on StackExchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145626/email-and-username-inconsistencies-on-stackexchange-com)

[image]

My name is only Naftali on [mi.yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/719/naftali), how did it come to be that on the top of the Stack Exchange menu bar?

---

When I click on "Naftali" it goes to: https://stackexchange.com/users/271284/naftali and then redirects to: https://stackexchange.com/users/271284/neal

---

My flair says "Neal" as well and **not** "Naftali":
[image]

---

Another example from [Ben Brocka](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160397/my-names-do-not-match-on-the-stack-exchange-main-site#comment464915_160397):

[image]

Comment: It must be a conspiracy!

Comment: @Oded haha I don't know about that :-P

Comment: I vaguely remember something of a last changed name being selected for the network profile something something?....let's see if I can find what I vaguely remember....

Comment: @Bart haha but mi.yodeya wasn't my last changed! and even if it was, why don't both of the names say the same thing?

Comment: Something something.....

Comment: I get this same problem. Everything is correct but the top bar name. It's not the most recent name.

Comment: @BenBrocka screenshot so I can add to the post?

Comment: Poor little fella, it'll be alright.  Don't you worry your wittle head about that link bein' wrong.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hqs6v.png

Comment: @BenBrocka added. Thanks.

Comment: Uh close voters, this is not too-localized, my SE.com profile has displayed like this for 6+ months

Comment: @BenBrocka yea. It was a test by me on the start. I voted to close as localized right when I asked the question, just to see what would happen. But now I see others are having the same issue, **this is _not_ too localized**

Comment: Ahhh now that is possible @ShaWizDowArd ‮